# How to find contents URI for SMS?

Tags: android

Is there a way to figure out a contents URI for SMS data for a specific android device?
For example, I was able to locate the DB containing all messages following [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16915/where-on-the-file-system-are-sms-messages-stored).

SMS DB is located at `./dbdata/databases/com.android.providers.telephony/mmssms.db`

However, I want to know the contents URI rather than the actual location *(e.g. contents://sms)*. Is this possible? If not, how do I gather information about stored SMS messages from different devices that have different and unknown content URIs for SMS?

For example, these are the contents URI for some vendors:

1. LG: `content://com.lge.messageprovider/msg/inbox`
2. SAMSUNG: `content://com.sec.mms.provider/message`
3. SAMSUNG Galaxy A: `content://com.btb.sec.mms.provider/message`
4. General: `content://sms/inbox`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use uri parser of `Contentresolver`, especially that you know content string.
Try this (in connection with `Cursor`):

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveTofirst();

    //read all messages in your inbox
    do
    {
        String message = "";
        //read all data from all available columns for each message
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            message += " " + cursor.getComulnName(i) + ": " + cursor.getString(i);
            //here do wathever you want with your message string
        }
    }
    while(cursor.moveToNext());

    cursor.close();
```

dont forget do add **READ_SMS** permission to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: The whole point of asking was that sms messages are not actually located in `content://sms` for some vendors.

Comment: which exactly? this code work perfectly fine on LG (GT540, P920), Samsung (S2, S3 mini, Trend) and HTC ONE